# I do not get the notion of stating a method or function in a variable

Tags: javascript

I am a javascript newbie, and faced a somewhat basic problem.

```
function expand(element){
 var target = document.getElementById(element);
 var h = target.offsetHeight;
 var sh = target.scrollHeight;
 var loopTimer = setTimeout('expand(\''+element+'\')',8);
 if(h < sh){
     h += 5;
 }  else {
     clearTimeout(loopTimer);
 }
 target.style.height = h+"px";
 }
```

In the code above, loopTimer variable is stated(setTimeout). However, what I am confused about is that it is simply 'stated', and not actually 'called'. To make my question clear, 
I rather expected just

```
setTimeout('expand(\''+element+'\')',8);
```

Because if it is stated in the variable, it seems to me that this method or function is just saved in the loopTimer, and be never used... but the code seems to work even if the loopTimer has not yet been 'called'..

Comment: keep a link to the MDN Docs handy while learning  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setTimeout` function returns a timeout ID that can be used to cancel the timeout later.  This code is calling `setTimeout` and saving its result (the ID of the new timeout) in a variable so it can be passed to `clearTimeout` later.

To be clear:  you're not saving the `setTimeout` function in the variable; you're saving the *result of calling it*.  Just like `target` holds a DOM element returned by calling the `document.getElementById` function, not the function itself.

Comment: Thank you for understanding my question the right way! So  the code var loopTimer = setTimeout('expand(\''+element+'\')',8);  both calls the setTimeout , and at the same time saves the result? So you do not have to use setTimeout(blahblah..);  additionally?

Comment: Right.  Just like `var n = 1 + 2` both calculates the sum and saves it in a variable.  The expression to the right of the equals sign is evaluated (for a function, this means calling it to get its return value), and the result of that evaluation is stored into the variable on the left.